# MongoDB running in MacOs High Sierra is with write operations very slow

Tags: mongodb, macos-high-sierra

I was running MongoDB 3.0 on my macbook with Sierra for proposal development, but after updating it to High Sierra, the write operations becomes so slow. I've tried to google about this matter but any results. I've changed my storage to WiredTiger nothing happens. Have anyone updated and got the same problem that I'm having here?

I'm putting my actual mongo.conf:

```
systemLog:

  destination: file

  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log

  logAppend: true

storage:

  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb

  engine: "wiredTiger"

net:

  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be an issue with Apple's new file system (APFS):

> MongoDB 3.6 is not tested on APFS, the new filesystem in macOS 10.13 and may encounter errors.

Source: [the mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Comment: Exactly the same issue. After updating to High Sierra the mongod service slows my computer to a halt